# Informix today operator

Tags: informix

I have a condition qa.actual_date >= today - 1 in a informix query.
Does it fetch the records exactly from the past 24 hours?

Eg:
Curent date and time is 13 Jun 2019 12:45 PM
does qa.actual_date >= today - 1 will fetch the records from 12 Jun 2019 12:45 PM or 12 Jun 2019 12:00 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Informix, a DATE value refers to a day, and has no explicit time component.  Given a current date of 2019-06-13 and assuming the type of `qa.actual_date` is DATE (and not a DATETIME type), the condition:

```
qa.actual_date >= TODAY - 1
```

selects all records where the `qa.actual_date` value is (any time on) 2019-06-12 or later.

If `qa.actual_date` is of type `DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND` or any other type that has an hour, minute, or second component (as well as day, month, year components), then the value of `TODAY - 1` will be converted (extended) to that type, and the missing time components will be treated as zeroes.

```
SELECT EXTEND(TODAY - 1, YEAR TO SECOND) FROM sysmaster:sysdual;
```

That will return `2019-06-12 00:00:00`.